# Android implement analytics in AOP style programming

Tags: android, google-analytics, aop

In Spring framework we will implement the AOP style programming for logging & security like features to resolve the Cross cutting problem.
In android i want to implement any analytic & logging in AOP style of Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for it. Its not using the `Google Analytics` but the approach is good. I got one **library** which is the best solution for my problem. This gives you `AOP` style, using annotation we can implement the analytics. 
[Track Analytics](https://github.com/orhanobut/tracklytics)
Google Analytics is using the style of AOP.[Here is link](http://blog.egorand.me/going-aspect-oriented-with-aspectj-and-google-analytics/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=9ed0cecaff-Android_Weekly_186&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-9ed0cecaff-337899329)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) under Andoid. Just use your favourite web search engine and enter the two words:

```
aspectj android
```

Enjoy!